# Combobox is not populating after form validation fails - Spring 3 MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring mvc for my web application. I have a simple form with some textfields and combo-boxes.

**Problem:** I am submitting the form with null values and it performs the validation. Since the null values are there so validation shows the form again but with blank combo-boxes. When the form is displayed for the first time, everything works fine.

Here is the code. How can I populate them with last selected values?

VIEW FILE

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="screening">

<table>
<!-- Text Form -->
    <tr>
        <td>EPI ID</td>
        <td><form:input path="epi_Id" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="epi_Id" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <!-- Combo-Box -->
        <td>Enrollment Center</td>            
        <td>
            <form:select path="enrollmentCenter">
            <form:options items="${epiCentersList}" itemValue="centerID" itemLabel="name"/>
            </form:select>
        </td>

        <td><form:errors path="enrollmentCenter" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form:form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ScreeningForm")
@SessionAttributes("screening")

public class ScreeningFormController {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(Model model)
{
    ScreeningDomain screen=new ScreeningDomain();
    model.addAttribute("screening", screen);        
    model.addAttribute("epiCentersList", usc.getAllEpiCentersList());
    return "ScreeningForm";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("screening") ScreeningDomain screeningDomain, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status)
{
    ScreeningServiceImpl screenService = new ScreeningServiceImpl();
    screeningValidator.validate(screeningDomain, result);
    if (result.hasErrors())
    {
        UtilityServiceClass usc=new UtilityServiceClass();
        model.addAttribute("epiCentersList", usc.getAllEpiCentersList());
        model.addAttribute("screening", screeningDomain);
        return "ScreeningForm";
    }
    else
    {
        screenService.add(screeningDomain);
        return "redirect:ScreeningForm";
    }
}
```

}

Everything else is working fine.
I thing model is loosing list object **"epiCentersList"** values but I cant figure out why.

Comment: You don't have `UtilityServiceClass usc=new UtilityServiceClass();` in setupForm()?? Is this line erasing all your EpiCentersList in submitForm(). Check if it needs to be removed!?

Answer (score 4):

In the controller method in which you are Validating your form data you need to add
the List again in the model object using :

```
if(result.hasErrors()) {
    model.addAttribute("YourListName",yourList);
    return "inputForm";
}
```

Comment: Or you can also bind it as a session attribute and then you don't have to be dealing with populating again and again, but yes, then it's more stateful :O/